# Handling Keystroke mouse with Delphi

Tags: delphi, mouseevent, keystroke

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to Detect Forward and Back Mouse Button Events in Delphi?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2458730/how-to-detect-forward-and-back-mouse-button-events-in-delphi)

I've a mouse with a previous and next buttons which work on any browser and file browser.

I would like to handle event of the "Previous button" in my Delphi app.

Is there somebody who have already do it ?

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

The solution has given by Craig Peterson.

```
type
  TMyForm = class(TForm)
  private
    procedure WMAppCommand(var Msg: TMessage); message WM_APPCOMMAND;
  end;

procedure TMyForm.WMAppCommand(var Msg: TMessage);
begin
  case GET_APPCOMMAND_LPARAM(Msg.LParam) of
    APPCOMMAND_BROWSER_BACKWARD:
    begin
      // Do "go back" code
      Msg.Result := 1;
    end;
  end;
end;
```